# Knockout template binding loseing state

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-templating

I'm using a template binding to render a set of radio buttons. There is also a css binding on the element.

When a radio button is clicked, the viewmodel & view are are updated, but the checked state of the radio button is lost. Is there a work around for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/d3YJc/1/

```
<div data-bind="with: point">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'template1', data: $data }, css: { 'has-warning': hasAlarm }"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="template1">
    <!-- ko foreach: choices -->
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: $parent.value, value: $data" name="test" />
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>        
    </label><br/>
    <!-- /ko -->    
    <span data-bind="visible: hasAlarm">Abnormal!</span>
</script>
```

Comment: Strangely if you use the template's `foreach` options it works: http://jsfiddle.net/FTnCd/ By the way it is working in your sample as well if you click twice on a label.

Comment: If you are using checkbox-es it is also not working: http://jsfiddle.net/RjH3E/. At this point I would say that you have found a bug but it seems it was fixed in version 3.0: http://jsfiddle.net/Ne48f/ So you should upgrade to 3.0 beta or you use my workaround from my previous comment.

Comment: I think it might have to do with the fact that all bindings are reevaluated each time. If so, maybe Knockout v3.0 will fix it.

Comment: @nemesv You should add that as the answer. It is definitely a bug.

Comment: @nemesv It works with `foreach` because it doesn't rerender if the data is the same, but with `data`, it does re-render. The root cause, though, is that all bindings for an element are updated together (before 3.0).

Comment: Actually the problem is a little different. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the order of the `checked` and `value` bindings. The `checked` binding uses the element's value to determine whether it should be checked or not. When the element is first bound, the value is set by the `value` binding after the `checked` binding is initialized. So the simplest fix is to re-order the bindings. Also I'd suggest you use the `attr` binding instead of `value` since `value` has extra overhead (it's a two-way binding designed for text boxes).

```
data-bind="attr: {value: $data}, checked: $parent.value"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/d3YJc/2/

Knockout 3.0 fixes the order problem also (in addition to the rendering issue mentioned in the comments), so that's another way to solve this.